# Why is the file csv in pandas stored incorrectly?

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm practicing csv files in pandas.But their output is like this Does anyone know the problem?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({
'nme' : ["aparna", "pankaj", "sudhir", "Geeku","seed","kasoo","jak","por"],
'deg' : ["MBA", "BCA", "M.Tech", "MBA","nba","jlk","esda","pin"],
'scr' : [90, 80,8, 98,34,5,23,22]})

df.to_csv('filel3.csv')
```

Comment: Actually, it is stored correctly, just your excel is opening the file as text and not as a csv file.  You instruct excel to open as text or uses csv formatting and delimit on commas.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a question, how do I set Excel to open the file like this?

Comment: Actually, try encoding it. That usually solves it for me. so use:

Comment: `df.to_csv('filel3.csv', encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: no.not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

use "sep=';'" in your to_csv method.
It could be that your Excel default settings are not on importing csv with ",". First try to add the comma in the Excel import csv settings.
 Otherwise you can use sep=';' to get work faster. But it depends to you.
Hope you are doing fine.
Kind regards.